# DataGrid SelectedItem to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have this code to populate my `DataGrid`:

```
private void getData()
{
    var context = new dbStudentEntities();        
    var data = (from s in context.tblStudents
                join c in context.tblClasses
                on s.classID equals c.classID
                select new {
                        s.studentID, c.classID, s.firstName, s.middleName, 
                        s.lastName, s.age, c.className});

    dgStudents.ItemsSource = data.ToList();
}
```

Now I want my TextBox filled with the SelectedItem in DataGrid. I have this code in my SelectionChanged event:

```
dbStudentEntities context = new dbStudentEntities();
try
{
    txtFirst.Text = ((tblStudent)dgStudents.SelectedItem).firstName.ToString();
    txtMiddle.Text = ((tblStudent)dgStudents.SelectedItem).middleName.ToString();
    txtLast.Text = ((tblStudent)dgStudents.SelectedItem).lastName.ToString();
    txtAge.Text = ((tblStudent)dgStudents.SelectedItem).age.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
}
```

But every time I select a row, this error pops up:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType0`7[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String]'
>   to type 'EFStudents.tblStudent'.

What should I do?

Comment: You're not adding a tblStudent object to the list. I'm not sure if you can do this in winforms but in wpf you would just add a list of tblStudent objects as ItemsSource to the listView. new { } is an anonimous class so the error makes sense

Comment: Im using WPF and im not using listview.

Comment: Then there is no trouble at all. just look at my answer and you should be good to go if you have the AutoGenerateColumns="True" on your DataGrid

Comment: Sorry to ask this sir, but how? I'm new to wpf.

Comment: I think the error is here: `((**tblStudent**)dgStudents.SelectedItem).firstName.ToString();`. Because I have join linq query to populate my DataGrid, but I only get the SelectedItem from tblStudent. I don't know what to replace it.

Comment: Try looking at the type selectedItem returnes because it is not tblStudent. It's some vague dbObject. You can even try to print it useing SelectedItem.GetType().ToString() so you're sure

Comment: GetType() returns this: `'<>f__AnonymousType07[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable1[System.Int32],System.String]` which is the datatype of my tblStudent columns

Comment: I tried replacing tblStudent with DataRowView like this:
`txtFirst.Text = ((DataRowView)dgStudents.SelectedItem).Row["firstName"].ToString();`
Now the error is:
`Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType07[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable1[System.Int32],System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'`'

Comment: That's because you try to use a DatRowView as a Dictionary witch is not possible. try my updated answer if you can get data to be a list of tblStudent objects the rest will be easy

Answer (score 0):

In your .xaml file:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgStudents" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

To create a list of object can you try:

```
List<tblStudent> data = context.tblStudents.ToList();
dgStudent.ItemsSource = data;
```

I might have made a few syntax errors so look what the compiler errors are if it doesn't work.

First make sure de data is in the datagrid and then you can worry about what happens when you select an item.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'EFStudents.dbStudentEntities' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EFStudents.tblStudent>' EFStudents

Comment: That means your context is not a List of tblStudents. Then try var like in my answer

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'EFStudents.dbStudentEntities' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Can you select at least one object from EFStudents.dbStudentEntities? You can't do anything if it's not clear what kind of objectcollection this is? What is the type of EFStudents.dbStudentEntities?

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'dbStudentModel.tblStudent' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'

Comment: What does it say when you hover your mouse over context.tblStudents or context.tblClasses?

Comment: System.Data.Entity.DbSet<tblStudent> dbStudentEntities.tblStudents {get; set;}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, I will assume that you use EntityFramework and your Student class looks something ike that:

```
public class Student
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;} // and other names and age and so on
   public ICollection<Class> Classes {get;set;} // classes to which student attends
}

// your context

public class dbStudentEntities : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Student> tblStudents {get;set;} // in CodeFirst this is enough to also create Classes table
}

//    then to populate DataGrid:

using(var ctx = new dbStudentEntities()) // this is your context, disposing it is important
{
   var students = ctx.Students.Include(x => x.Classes).ToList(); // Student.Classes is not virtual, so we don't have lazy loading, but making it virtual creates ugly proxy. You can read up on that
   dataGrid.ItemsSource = students;
}
```

You don't need that ugly LINQ - EF can do the work for you.

Now DataGrid.SelectedItem will be of type Student, so you can use your casting.